# Несколько вопросов по защите сайта

Tags: безопасность

Я недавно занялся созданием сайта и нашел информацию о xss атаках и mysql иньекциях.

1. Что такое xss атаки и mysql иньекции, как можно от них защититься
   (если можете опишите ну или дайте ссылку где об этом хорошо
   написано)
2. Есть какие-либо еще угрозы, кроме тех, что перечислены выше?
3. Обязательно ли шифровать пароли в базе (если защитить свой сайт, то не думаю что в этом есть необходимость)

Comment: Об этом можно ооочень долго рассказывать. Но чтобы не допускать дыр в безопасности, надо сперва приобрести опыт...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара-тройка советов:

- используйте параметризованный запросы к базе, или ORM, если уж на то пошло, и никаких `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = $Id"`
- заменяйте все `<` и `>` на `&lt;` и `&gt;` в любом поле, которое заполняет пользователь
- хешируйте пароли ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО, к тому же все записи паролей будут одинаковой длинны

да и это не полный список, но, извините, по остальным проблемам ничего сказть не могу

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с  Asen, это довольно-таки обширная тема.Требующая хороших знаний технологий.

Подробный список и описание можно посмотреть [здесь.](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246978/Threat-Classification)